# How to use Sequelize Transaction inside a node-schedule job?

Tags: node.js, cron, transactions, sequelize.js, node-schedule

How do I use `Sequelize` `Transaction` insde a `node-schedule` job?

For example I have this function here:

```
    async doSomething(
        params
    ) {

        // Create > Transaction1
        const transaction1 = await sequelize.transaction();

        try {
        
            await this._conversation.update(
                {
                    status: 'something'
                }, {
                    where: {
                        id: conversation.id
                    },
                    transaction: transaction1,
                })
                .then(data => {
    
                    // Do Nothing
    
                })
                .catch(err => {
    
                    // Throw > Error
    
                });
        

            /*
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Schedule > Job
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            */
            
            schedule_date = "some schedule date"
            
            const job = schedule.scheduleJob(
                "campaign_" + campaign.id, // Job ID
                schedule_date, // Schedule Date
                async function(){

                    // Create > Transaction2
                    const transaction2 = await sequelize.transaction();

                    try {

                        let create_result = await this._campaign.create(data, {
                            transaction: transaction2
                        })
                            .then(data => {
    
                                // Do Nothing
    
                            })
                            .catch((err) => {
    
                                // Throw > Error
    
                            });
                            
                        await transaction2.commit();

                    }
                    catch (err)
                    {
            
                        // DB > Rollback
                        await transaction2.rollback();
            
                    }  

                }, () => {

                });
                    
            await transaction1.commit(); 
            
        }
        catch (err)
        {

            // DB > Rollback
            await transaction1.rollback();

            // Throw > Error Object
            throw err

        }        
                        
    }
```

You can see in the function,
I have a `sequelize` `update()` using `transaction1` and `sequelize` `create()` inside the `node-schedule` `job` using `transaction2`

Is this correct?

Comment: Why do you need an outer transaction? Do you expect errors while scheduling a job (not executing it on a scheduled time)?

Comment: hi, the outer transaction (`transaction1`) is for other CRUD operations like `update()`, `create()` etc inside `async doSomething()`

Comment: Well, looks like both transactions are independent, because the scheduled job is executed later after the transaction 1 will be finished

Comment: I see, what about the `objects` passed into the  `async function(){ ... }` of the `schedule.scheduleJob()`? are they like cached for future use? will their values change?

Comment: Do you mean `data`? Where does it come from?